# Exception occurred at PC=0x004000a8 -> (Abort after) -> Followed by Unaligned address in inst/data fetch: 0x1001012b

Tags: arrays, mips, memory-address, memory-alignment, qtspim

I am attempting to recreate a C-snippet in assembly. The C program essentially:

- creates a char array[256] along with a pointer *A initialized to NULL.
- User input of some string is then stored into the char array
- while each ith element of the array != 0
- check it the ith element is == some DEFINED char value V.
- If array[i] == V -> set A = &array[i]
- break
- Lastly check if A is still initialized to NULL
  if not pint address and value of A
- else not found

Unfortunately, when I run the MIPS code with `Qtspim` I get the aforementioned error Exception occurred at PC=0x004000a8 
-> (Abort after) 
-> Followed by Unaligned address in inst/data fetch: 0x1001012b

I feel like it has something to do with the way that I store my byte values in the array or the way I am accessing those memory locations but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any insight that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated. Happy holidays everyone!

Bellow is my assembly code:

```
# global functions aforementioned error
    .globl main 

# .text assembler directive
    .text       

# main
main:
    # register map 
    # use $t0 for i
    # use $t1 for NULL
    # use $s0 for &inputArray[i]
    # use $s1 for indexed array value
    # use $s2 for the base address inputArray
    # use $s3 for result
    # use $t2 for constCharlwr


# Prompt user for input
    la $a0, str1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

# Get user input and store in input array

    la $a0, inputArray
    li $a1, 256
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

# set up registers
    lb $t0, i 
    lb $t1, NULL
    la $s2, inputArray
    lb $s3, result
    lb $t2, constCharlwr
    li $s0, 0
    add $s0, $s0, $s2  # s0 =  &arrayA[i]

    while:                           # while loop

        add $s0, $s0, $t0            # base address + 1 byte
        lb  $s1, 0($s0)              # load array index value into s1
        beq $s1, $t1, outsideWhile   # inputArray[i] != '\0'

        if1:
            bne  $s1, $t2, outsideIf # check if inputArray[i] == e 
            move $s3, $s1            # if true copy s1(inputArray[i] into s3(result)
            sb   $s3, result
            j outsideWhile
        outsideIf:
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j while

    outsideWhile:

        if2:
            beq $s3, $t1, else
            # Print results
            # Print string 2
            lw $a0, str2
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print address of result
            la $a0, result
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print next line
            lb $a0, nextline
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print string 3
            lw $a0, str3
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print result char value
            lb $a0, result
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print next line
            lb $a0, nextline
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            j exitPrgm
        else:
            # Print No match
            lw $a0, str4
            li $v0, 4
            syscall


# Exit the program by means of syscall.

    exitPrgm:
    li $v0, 10 # Sets $v0 to "10" to select exit syscall
    syscall # Exit

# .data assembler directive
    .data

    inputArray:   .space 256
    constCharlwr: .byte  'e'
    result:       .byte  0
    NULL:         .byte  0
    i:            .byte  0

    str1:       .asciiz "Enter a word to search for letter e: \n"
    str2:       .asciiz "First match at address "
    str3:       .asciiz "The matching character is "
    str4:       .asciiz "No match found\n"
    nextline:   .asciiz "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out my initial problem, I was not using la for my sys calls and once I fixed that I started getting the output that I wanted. The only problem now is I can figure out how to print the actual address of the result. Can someone help me with this.
New Code, Trying a few diffrent things to get the memory address but nothing seems to work.

```
    # Prompt user for input
    la $a0, str1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Get user input and store in input array

    la $a0, inputArray
    li $a1, 255
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    # set up registers
    lb $t0, i 
    lb $t1, NULL
    la $s2, inputArray
    lb $s3, result
    lb $t2, constCharlwr
    li $s0, 0
    add $s0, $s0, $s2  # s0 =  &arrayA[i]

    while:                           # while loop

        add $s0, $s0, $t0            # base address + 1 byte
        lb  $s1, 0($s0)              # load array index value into s1
        beq $s1, $t1, outsideWhile   # inputArray[i] != '\0'

        if1:
            bne  $s1, $t2, outsideIf # check if inputArray[i] == e 
            sb   $s1, result 
            j outsideWhile
        outsideIf:
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j while

    outsideWhile:

        if2:
            beq $s1, $t1, else
            # Print results
            # Print string 2
            la $a0, str2
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print address of result
            la $t9, result
            li $t8, 4 
            li $t0, 0 
            #for:
            #    bge $t0, $t8  outsideFor  
            #    add $t9, $t9, $t0
            #    lb $t7, 0($t9)  
            #    sb $t7, resultAddr
            #    la $a0, resultAddr
            #    li $v0, 4
            #    syscall

            #    addi $t0, $t0, 1
            #    j for
            #outsideFor:
            sb 0($t9)  resultAddr
            la $a0, resultAddr
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            sb 1($t9)  resultAddr
            la $a0, resultAddr
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            sb 2($t9)  resultAddr
            la $a0, resultAddr
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            sb 3($t9)  resultAddr
            la $a0, resultAddr
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            # Print next line
            la $a0, nextline
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print string 3
            la $a0, str3
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print result char value
            la $a0, result
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            # Print next line
            la $a0, nextline
            li $v0, 4
            syscall

            j exitPrgm
        else:
            # Print No match
            la $a0, str4
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
```